# Delphi PNG images collection in a component

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-xe7

today my question is about creating a collection of PNG images in a component.
I found a button that accept a PNG image as a gliph, but it use a PNG image composed by the four states of the image like this:

[image]

I've modified the component for using four differents images, each one for a single state. So, my components looks like this:

```
  ...
  public
    FPngImgEnabled: TPngImage;
    FPngImgDisabled: TPngImage;
    FPngImgDown: TPngImage;
    FPngImgOver: TPngImage;
    FDown: Boolean;
    Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    Destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Paint; override;
  published
    property PngImgEnabled: TPngImage read FPngImgEnabled write SetPngImgEnabled;
    property PngImgDisabled: TPngImage read FPngImgDisabled write SetPngImgDisabled;
    property PngImgDown: TPngImage read FPngImgDown write SetPngImgDown;
    property PngImgOver: TPngImage read FPngImgOver write SetPngImgOver;
  ...
```

Is this way I've a component with four PNG images and then for SetPng... procedures. I wonder if there is a way to use a collection of the four PNG images; something like "TPNGImagesList" for concentrate the images in a single place.

Comment: what's wrong with a `TImageList`?

Comment: There is TPngImageList contained in [PngComponents](https://code.google.com/archive/p/cubicexplorer/downloads). Maybe this fits your needs. Maybe there's even a readymade button included - I haven't checked.

Comment: Accompanied by: What's wrong with TPNGImageList either? BTW, which Delphi version?

Comment: Which version of Delphi?  If you have access to generics, why not use that?  Make a type `TImageState = (isEnabled, isDisabled, isDown, isOver);`, then use a `TObjectDictionary<TImageState, TPngImage>`.  Bonus that the dictionary can own the image objects and free them itself.

Comment: The version of Delphi I use is XE7

Comment: If you have XE7 you can have a look at the standard TButton. It uses an imagelist (which can also be a TPngImageList) and has ImageIndex, HotImageIndex, DisabledImageIndex, PressedImageIndex, SelectedImageIndex and StylusHotImageIndex. That should at least give you an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this:

```
  type
    TImgType = (itEnabled, itDisabled, itDown, itOver);


  ...
  protected
    procedure SetImg(Index: TImgType; Value: TPngImage);
    function  GetImg(Index: TImgType): TPngImage;      
  public
    FImages: TList<TPngImage>;
    FDown: Boolean;
    Constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    Destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Paint; override;
  published
    property Image[Index:TImgType]: TPngImage read GetImg write SetImg;
    property PngImgEnabled: TPngImage index itEnabled read GetImg write SetImg;
    property PngImgDisabled: TPngImage index itDisabled read GetImg write SetImg;
    property PngImgDown: TPngImage index itDown read GetImg write SetImg;
    property PngImgOver: TPngImage index itOver read GetImg write SetImg;

  ...
```